# how to add column to column family in hbase

Tags: java, command-line, hbase

I am new to hbase. Can you show me how to add column to a column family. I have data like this:

```
{
name: abc
addres: xyz
}
```

I have a table test with column family person. How can I add name and address as a column to this person. Please show me in hbase command line as well as java.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

HBase Shell :

From the Hbase shell wiki : http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#shell

Put a cell 'value' at specified table/row/column and optionally timestamp coordinates.  To put a cell value into table 't1' at row 'r1' under column 'c1' marked with the time 'ts1', do:

```
hbase> put 't1', 'r1', 'c1', 'value', ts1
```

something like this in your case :

```
hbase> put 'test', 'yourRow', 'person:name', 'abc'
hbase> put 'test', 'yourRow', 'person:address', 'xyz'
```

In Java :

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
HTable table = new HTable(config, "test");

Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("yourRow"));
p.add(Bytes.toBytes("person"), Bytes.toBytes("name"),
    Bytes.toBytes("abc"));
table.put(p);
```

Comment: do you know if Hbase tread "person:name" any different than any other name? In other words, does the ":" has special meaning in hbase or it just tread the whole as a string?

Comment: The value provides need to be in this format : "<family>:<qualifier>". The <qualifier> is the name of the column in your column family and <family> is the column family

Comment: I can see I must have the first family column, but if I want to add another column of column like "person:name:firstname", does the "name:firstname" being treated special in hbase?

Comment: You can't do that, you can't have embedded column families... in that case avoid using person:name and use person:firstname directly

Comment: Hbase works with column family and qualifier, the qualifier does not need to be define like the column family, it can be anything, you can have as many qualifiers as you want in a column family

Comment: in the java example, you can set the Column Family to "person" and the Column Qualifier to "name:firstname": p.add(Bytes.toBytes("person"), Bytes.toBytes("name:firstname"),
    Bytes.toBytes("Sean"));

All row keys, column family names, column qualifiers, and values are just byte arrays, so they can be anything you want them to be.  That is the purpose of the Bytes.toBytes(val) call

Answer (score 6):

JP Bond gave you the sample code you need - I just wanted to add that one of the nice things about HBase is since it is sparse (i.e. doesn't reserve column space for rows with out values). One of the features for this design decision is that you can create a new column (column family + qualifier) just by writing for it.